# What's the meaning of rebase in magit status buffer?

Tags: magit

In magit status buffer, it said:

```
Head:     feature/event
Rebase:   origin/feature/event123
Tag:      8000.102 (9)
```

But if run git status, I don't see such Rebase information if simply run the following in command line

```
git status
```

What's the meaning of Rebase here?

Comment: This is a guess, it's roughly the same idea as displaying the upstream branch. I.e. the most recent ancestor of the branch you are at now. This would happen if you configured `pull` to rebase instead of merge, or if you merged `feature/event` onto `origin/feature/event123` (notice the onto).

Comment: @wvxvw yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Until recently the line would have been:

```
Upstream:  origin/feature/event123
```

which tells you that `feature/event`s upstream branch is `origin/feature/event123`.

I have changed it so that either "Merge" or "Rebase" is shown instead of "Upstream". "Rebase" is shown if `branch.feature/event.rebase` is true, "Merge" otherwise.